# Can't make my program generate a random card (1-13)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class that will have the following:

```
Class name:              Card

 Data attributes:       
   __value
   __face_value

 Methods:
   __init__() – initialize value to 0 and face_value to an empty string
   deal() – generates a random card, assigns the value, calls the set_face_value method
   set_value() – assigns an integer card value to the value attribute
   set_face_value() – sets the face_value based on the what the value attribute is
   get_value() – returns the value of the attribute value
   get_face_value() – returns the value of the attribute face_value
   __str__() – returns the state of the object
```

This program, will use the "deal" method in my class and will generate a random number, than it will send it to get_face_value to return the face for the card for example: like 2 = Ace, 10 = ten.

This is my program so far:

```
import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0
        face_value = {}

    def deal(self, get_face_value):
        return random.randit(1,13)  

    def set_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def get_value(self, find_face_value):
        return self.__value

    def find_face_value(self):
        self.__value = {'1': 'Ace', 'A': 'Ace', 'J': 'Jack', '11': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', '12': 'Queen', 'K': 'King', '13': 'King'}

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__value

    def main():
        card = Card()
        card.deal()
        print (card)
```

So the idea of this program is that it will generate a random card every time I execute it but I cant seen to figure it out how to put the finish product. What can I do to generate a random card. Here is my error everytime I execute it:

```
TypeError: deal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'face_value'
```

Comment: `def deal(self, get_face_value):` ... `card.deal()` Do you see the problem? Also, It looks like you did not share the exact code you are executing. Note the different variable names.

Comment: Can you please format your code properly here with the proper indentation assuming that your methods are supposed to be within the card class

Comment: You have a list of method signatures but it seems to me you haven't a clear idea of what the methods are supposed to do. Start by writing a docstring for each method that says what input it is expecting and what happens when it is called. For example the method `deal` as your code defines it expects a parameter, but does nothing with it. Your spec, on the other hand, says it expects no parameters but should call the function `self.get_face_value(random.randint(1,13))`. Note: randi*n*t not randit.

Comment: Please post the code that you really start. The code in the question is not runnable.

Comment: yes I misspelled randint, my fault. I'm new to this website so I don't really know how to input the code in here, I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Your methods `def deal(self, get_face_value)` and `def get_value(self, find_face_value)` require a positional argument (`get_face_value` and `find_face_value` respectively). But going by what those methods do, I reckon you don't need them.

In fact, I'm not sure why you would include them there and I suspect the concepts of parameters and arguments are not clear to you.

Additionally, your `deal` and `set_value` methods don't seem to do what you probably want them to do. "Getter" methods like your `get_value` are supposed to return something, but "setter" methods like `set_value` are supposed to *set* those values, not return them (or at least not exclusively). With the code you showed us, `get_value` and `set_value` do the exact same thing, and `deal` doesn't set the card's value to the random number you generate, but simply returns that value after generating it (and doing nothing else with it).

Going by your pseudo code, what you want is probably similar to the following:

```py
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.face_value = ""  # You mention this should be a string. In your example it's an empty dictionary instead.

    def deal(self):
        self.set_value(random.randint(1, 13)  # You originally typoed "randit".

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
        # Here we set the value attribute and then call the set_face_value.
        self.set_face_value()

    def set_face_value(self):
        # Here we use the card's own value attribute to determine what face value to give it, using a dictionary lookup.
        faces = {}  # I'll leave compiling the lookup dictionary to you.
        # Just notice that the key has to be an integer of the ones you generated above
        # in the format 1: "Ace", 2: "Two", 3: "Three" etc.
        self.face_value = faces[self.value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.face_value

def main():
    card = Card()
    card.deal()
    print(card)
```

Of course there are many ways to make this code much better but I preferred to keep it both simple and somewhat similar to yours to show you what was wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you! i will try this out

Comment: Is telling me that values is not defined?

Comment: @EdgarRotundo Ah, sorry, I had a slight oversight in my code. Replace `self.face_value = values[self.value]` with `self.face_value = faces[self.value]`.
The `__str __` function should also return `self.face_value` without the parentheses.